# Get NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I get a NULL value as well in this query:

```
SELECT x_month FROM end_months WHERE x_month = 201907
```

This shows the month because it exists but I also want to have another row if it doesnt exist (Not another column)

Comment: You could use  `Month is null`

Comment: Hint:  `x_month = 201907 OR x_month IS NULL`.

Comment: Nope -- I still get one row if I use OR whereas I would like to get two rows:

Comment: @Kash Then x_month does not have any null values.

Comment: So basically if I enter two values; 201907 and 201908 then I only get one row which exists but I would like to see another one saying NULL or something which means that one row exists and the other doesnt

Comment: @SMor True the field doesnt have NULL but I wanted to show NULL or a message when the value is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following technique:

```
With cte as (
    SELECT x_month 
    FROM end_months 
    WHERE x_month = 201907
)

Select x_month
From cte
Union all
Select null
Where not exist (
    select 1 from cte
)
```

The second query will add a row with `null` if the cte returns no results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the clause `OR`

```
SELECT x_month
FROM end_months
WHERE
    x_month = 201907 
    OR x_month IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried but I get only one row. Basically if I enter two values; 201907 and 201908 then I only get one row which exists but I would like to see another one saying NULL or something which means that one row exists and the other doesnt

Comment: But that rows which x_month is NULL exist? If you omit the clause WHERE it  does get rows with NULL value on x_month column? If it does, this select should bring it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL
AND write another select query for not exist month